# How to fill canny edges that are not fully connected?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

Hi All I have the following image after using canny to detect the edges of crack. However, I was trying to fill up the gap between the edges. However, since the gaps are not fully closed it fill up the whole image. The code I used as shown below:

```
# Read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('Output-Set/Edges.tif', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get the (largest) contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw white filled contour on black background
result = np.zeros_like(img)
cv2.drawContours(result, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), cv2.FILLED)
plt.imshow(result)

plt.imshow(result)

# save results
#cv2.imwrite('knife_edge_result.jpg', result)
```

The Image I am trying to fill is shown below:

[image: Edges Extraction Using Canny]

The original image is shown below. I have used canny to extract the edges of the cracks in the original image but needed to fill them up.

[image: Original Image]

Comment: first of all where is the canny in your code ?

Comment: @Abdullah. can u post original image??

Comment: What do you want to fill? The whole circle? If you are able to group your edges (tell ehich edge belongs to the shape you want to fill an which doesnt) you can try to connect those with some strategy. A simple strategy could be to connect by convexHull. More sophisticated strategies could be found in 3D object reconstruction from point clouds

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ explain: _why_ do you do what you do? what's it for?

Comment: Canny detects salient edges, it does not extract a continuous contour for a region, which is what you seem to be after. So, Canny is not the right thing to apply. You might need to apply a watershed instead, it depends on what your input image looks like.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I have uploaded the original image.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I have used the canny to extract the edges from the original image attached.

Comment: So your goal is to detect/segment the cracks? There are many methods described in the literature for such a task. I would certainly not use Canny for this problem. Just a plain threshold will net you the thicker cracks. Use something like Frangi’s vesselness to detect the thinner ones.