# Mask Edge detected Images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, edge-detection

Hi All I am new to image processing and I was developing a code to detect cracks within an image. The purpose of the code is to build a machine learning algorithm to help detecting and quantifying cracks within an image. The images attached below shows the image before and after processing. I have been trying to mask the area between the edges using morphology for visualizing and quantifying purposes based on total area of masked image but it is not doing the job as some of the major cracks are left unmasked after applying the morphology transformation. Hope if someone can help me with this. The code used is also shown here.

```
# importing necessary libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# read a cracked sample image
img = cv2.imread('Input-Set/Original.tif')

# Convert into gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Image processing ( smoothing )
# Averaging
blur = cv2.blur(gray,(3,3))

# Apply logarithmic transform
img_log = (np.log(blur+1)/(np.log(1+np.max(blur))))*255
# Specify the data type
img_log = np.array(img_log,dtype=np.uint8)

# Image smoothing: bilateral filter
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_log, 5, 75, 75)

# Canny Edge Detection
edges = cv2.Canny(bilateral,20,20)

# Morphological Closing Operator
kernel = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Create feature detecting method
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1500)

# Make featured Image
keypoints, descriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(closing, None)
featuredImg = cv2.drawKeypoints(closing, keypoints, None)

# Create an output image
cv2.imwrite('Output-Set/Edges.tif', edges)
cv2.imwrite('Output-Set/Morphology.tif', closing)
```

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiSdo.png) [Edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnBY8.png) [Morphology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjgRU.png)

Comment: I would suggest you just threshold on the gray color of the cracks, if I understand the part you want.  Use cv2.inRange().  See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981. That will be your mask. You can then make the rest of your input black or transparent, using the mask

Comment: same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73676403/how-to-fill-canny-edges-that-are-not-fully-connected -- I remember these pics. you asked this before. people recommended that you **not** do Canny, but instead simply threshold on the level, or try some kind of "vesselness" filter.

Comment: (N+1)th post striving to get something out of edge detection, when the image binarizes like a charm... But what exactly are you trying to measure ?

Comment: new question (new account): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951351/image-segmentation-to-map-cracks